# Getting values from a basic Slider jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm having trouble getting the values from a 2 way (range) jquery slider. I have tried various things but none worked.

My text field which contains the info has [int - int] structure.

What I am trying to do is to get the 2 range values from the slider into the url get at the end of the script.

JavaScript:

```
var val1 = 0;
var val2 = 0;

$(function() {
    $( "#slider-3" ).slider({
        range:true,
        min: 1,
        max: {{ $data['labels'] }},
        values: [ 1, {{ $data['labels'] }} ],
        slide: function( event, ui ) {
           $( "#price" ).val( ui.values[ 0 ] + " - " + ui.values[ 1 ] );
           val1 = ui.values[0];
           val2 = ui.values[1];
        }
    });

    $( "#price" ).val( $( "#slider-3" ).slider( "values", 0 ) +
    " - " + $( "#slider-3" ).slider( "values", 1 ) );
});

$('#fetchLabels').on('click', function(){
    location.href="{{ url('labels/objects') }}/" + val1 + "/" + val2; 
});
```

**EDIT**: With some trouble shooting I am finding that the values are not getting set. They remain only at 0 and 0...

Comment: You might want to put some work on that code indentation, quite hard to read, really.

Comment: check the edit for easier to read code.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed this. Apparently the values are only changed when the bar moves. So I had to set the val 1 and val 2 to the appropriate starting point.

Javascript:

```
   var val1 = 1;
   var val2 = {{ $data['labels'] }};

    $(function() {

$( "#slider-3" ).slider({
   range:true,
   min: 1,
   max: {{ $data['labels'] }},
   values: [ 1, {{ $data['labels'] }} ],
   slide: function( event, ui ) {
        val1 = ui.values[ 0 ];
        val2 = ui.values[ 1 ];
      $( "#price" ).val( ui.values[ 0 ] + " - " + ui.values[ 1 ] );
   }
});
$( "#price" ).val( $( "#slider-3" ).slider( "values", 0 ) +
" - " + $( "#slider-3" ).slider( "values", 1 ) );
});

$('#fetchLabels').on('click', function(){

var urlee = "{{ url('label/objects') }}/" + val1 + "/" + val2;

 location.href=urlee; 

});
```